# Jemalloc Symbolication No Suitable Image Found Error

Tags: macos, crash, gatekeeper, ruby

I'm working with a custom built Ruby, compiled and built on a Mac OS command line with standard XCode command line tools. It brings in the jemalloc library for better memory management. Whenever I run this Ruby executable, and try to profile it with vmmap, heap, or leaks, I get an error like this:

```bsh
ruby -e "puts RUBY_VERSION; puts Process.pid; sleep" &
[3] 59251

❯ 2.7.4
59251
heap 59251 > /dev/null
2022-03-08 17:45:04.966 heap[59276:1918119] *** Symbolication:  Couldn't load /opt/carrier/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib to introspect target process's malloc zone named jemalloc_zone_0x106ba8a68: dlopen(/opt/carrier/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib, 261): no suitable image found.  Did find:
  /opt/carrier/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib: code signature in (/opt/carrier/lib/libjemalloc.2.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
2022-03-08 17:45:04.966 heap[59276:1918119] *** Symbolication:  no introspect structure for malloc zone jemalloc_zone_0x106ba8a68
2022-03-08 17:45:04.974 heap[59276:1918119] *** Symbolication:  no introspect structure for malloc zone jemalloc_zone_0x106ba8a68
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: How did you ionstall this? /opt/carrier is a very odd path so we need more information

Comment: This is a custom installation over which I have no control and with which I have little knowledge.

Comment: If a custom installer then you need to ask the people who supplied it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to code-sign the libjemalloc.2.dylib file, otherwise programs that load in that library will fail GateKeeper validation. Depending on your settings, you do not need an "official" signature, even an ad-hoc signature will do.

Alternatively you could include the entitlement `com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation` with the application binary itself. You can read Apple's documentation for that [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_cs_disable-library-validation?language=objc).

Comment: Thank you. I tried signing it ad-hoc, but when I ran the executable, I still got an error, though a slightly different one: "code signature...not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)"

Comment: How have you configured your GateKeeper settings? (System Preferences > Security & Privacy - Allow apps....) - Do you have SIP disabled?

Comment: "Allow apps downloaded from" is set to "App Store and identified developers". The only other choice is "App Store".

Comment: Regarding setting the entitlement with the application, the application is not a Mac app, it's a Ruby interpreter called on the command line. Can the entitlement be set on a library file or executable file? Also I have not disabled SIP, should I? I was thinking it would make my machine more vulnerable.